# how: shutdown computers connected via ethernet using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ethernet

I am a begginer in vb.net. I have two laptops connected using a cross-over cable.  one laptop is the server, the other is a client. what i want to happen is to shutdown the client pc using the server pc. This is my starting code,, please help :D

```
Public Class frmShutdown

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to cancel?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "Cancel shutdown") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        frmServer.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub frmShutdown_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height) / 2
    Me.Left = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width) / 2



End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub btnShutdown_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShutdown.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I know that we ask to post code to help but we ask to post code **related** to the question

Comment: the code will be placed inside the btnShutdown. i dont have any idea on how to start the code so the slot is empty.. please help me :D

Comment: The fastest way is the one explained in the answer below. Open a command prompt and type **SHUTDOWN /?** You can see a list of parameters for the shutdown command. You need only to figure out how to call this program using VB.NET. See the Process class on MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Private Sub btnShutdown_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShutdown.Click
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "-r -f -m \\YourClientPCName -t 30 ")
End Sub
```

Check this link:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the `shutdown` command passing the relevant parameters - particularly the `/m \\<computer name>` one if you have security permission.

Comment: i don't understand what you are talking about sir. im new in vb.net and do not know much about the language used . p[lease help me, thank you :D

Comment: Steve';s comment explains this a little better. You need to run he external command, look for the Process class in the MSDN docs.